# Problem generating Swagger definitions using custom naming strategy

Tags: c#, swagger, odata, swashbuckle

I have an OData Web API and I'm using Swashbuckle and Swagger to generate and display Web API documentation.  This was working and producing nice definition names, like so:

- User
- Role
- Permission
- ODataResponse[List[Permission]]
- CoordinateSystem
- Etc...

I ran into an issue with "Conflicting schemaIds" after adding some new objects and controllers and started getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Conflicting schemaIds: Duplicate schemaIds detected for types Microsoft.Spatial.CoordinateSystem and MyProject.CoordinateSystem. See the config setting - "UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds" for a potential workaround'
```

As the error states, I added the following line in SwaggerConfig.cs

```
c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
```

This fixed the error but caused some issues with my definition names.  Now they show up like this:

- MyProject.User
- MyProject.Role
- MyProject.Permission
- **Swashbuckle.OData.ODataResponse[System.Collections.Generic.List[MyProject.Permission]]**
- MyProject.CoordinateSystem
- Microsoft.Spatial.CoordinateSystem

The third last one is problematic now as it is too long for the app that reads this information.

Next, I tried using the custom strategy example provided in SwaggerConfig.cs to rename one of the conflicting definition names:

```
c.SchemaId(t => t.FullName.Contains("Microsoft.Spatial.CoordinateSystem") 
    ? t.FullName : t.Name);
```

This works for the conflicting definitions as it uses the full name for "Microsoft.Spatial.CoordinateSystem" and I get this now:

- User
- Role
- Permission
- **ODataResponse`1**
- CoordinateSystem
- Microsoft.Spatial.CoordinateSystem

The problem now is "ODataResponse`1".  I'm expecting "ODataResponse[List[Permission]]" but it is displaying the name of the Swashbuckle.OData definition only.  There are other options - I tried t.FullName, t.Name, t.AssemblyQualifiedName, t.Namespace but none produce the desired results.

I did come up with a solution that works using the custom naming strategy but it looks horrible and is super hacky:

```
c.SchemaId(t => t.FullName.Contains("System.Collections.Generic.List") ? 
    "ODataResponse[List[" + 
    t.FullName.Substring(t.FullName.IndexOf("MyProject.") + 10, (t.FullName.IndexOf(",") - 10 - t.FullName.IndexOf("MyProject.")))
    + "]]" 
    : (t.FullName.Contains("Microsoft.Spatial.CoordinateSystem") ? t.FullName : t.Name));
```

Does this seem to be a bug within Swagger/Swashbuckle or am I doing something wrong with the c.SchemaId code?

Comment: yes that is very strange that the `SchemaId` will change the ODataResponse like that, do you have a project somewhere reproducing this issue?

Comment: I'll have to create a sample project to show the behavior for this.